# Missing return statement in a for each loop

Tags: java, return

I'm getting the error "Missing return statement" with this code:

```
public String getAuthorFullName(String title)
{
    for (Book authorName : inventory)
        if (authorName.getTitle() != null)
        {
            return authorName.getAuthor().getName().getFullName();
        } 
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```

I want to return o  returns the full name of the author who wrote the book by this title or return null if there is no Book with this title, or if title is null or "".

I tried to put the code like this:

```
public String getAuthorFullName(String title)
{
    for (Book authorName : inventory)
        if (authorName.getTitle() != null)
        {
            return authorName.getAuthor().getName().getFullName();
        }
        return null;
```

But it always returns the first Author in the list...

Can somebody help me please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well yeah... you return the first one and thats its. You need to compare the `String title` with whatever and then if they match return that one. `Please do look through the logic of the loop. It makes sense why it is only returning the first`

Comment: The first thing to do is make your code clearer by *always* using braces for loops. For example, the indentation in your second code block suggests that `return null` is in the loop - but it's not. Life is *much* clearer with braces.

Comment: You might notice that you are checking for `!= null` and not for the same `title`. You might want to check this aswell..

Comment: I'd also strongly suggest using more meaningful names - a book isn't the same as an author name.

Comment: You are getting an error in the first code because the inventory may be empty so the if statement will not be executed. You need to compare the book.getTitle() with the method argument title in the if statement in order to not return the first book author

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
public String getAuthorFullName(String title)
{
    for (Book authorName : inventory) {
        if (authorName.getTitle() != null && authorName.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            return authorName.getAuthor().getName().getFullName();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and always use braces. It is much easier to live with them then without them.

Answer (score 1):

Your first case is missing a return statement because it is. Consider having an empty inventory. So the for loop will make no runs and neither the if statement or the else statement will be executed. And then there is no return statement left.

Your second case has a return statement that is not part of the for loop and so a correct java syntax. BUT you only check if `getTitle() != null`. And thats true for every case a title has been set, even if it is empty.

The equality of Strings is checked with `String.equals(String another)`. So what you really want to do is:

```
public String getAuthorFullName(String title){
    for (Book authorName : inventory)
        if (authorName.getTitle() != null && authorName.getTitle().equals(title))
            return authorName.getAuthor().getName().getFullName();
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getAuthorFullName(String title) {
    for (Book authorName : inventory) {
        if (authorName.getTitle() != null && authorName.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            return authorName.getAuthor().getName().getFullName();
        } 
    }
    return null;
}
```